# Cannot change the Delete Rule of a self referencing foreign-key-relationship to cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have the following table

```
[dbo].[myObj]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fk_ParentID] [int] NULL
)
```

and I have a relationship from `fk_ParentID` to `ID`.

I want to change the Delete Rule in SQL Server Management Studio under the Window "Foreign-Key Relationships"->Insert and Update Specifications->Delete Rule to ON Delete Cascade, but it is not possible.

Can you tell me why, and how I can make this possible?

Comment: At one level it does not appear as though you have a primary key on `[dbo].[myObj]`. However, even if you did, the other, deeper level is that you introduce multiple cascade paths.

[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) discusses this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further clarify this question, I've created a sample schema as such:

```
USE TempDB;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myObj]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_myObj PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [fk_ParentID] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT FK_myObj_ID FOREIGN KEY 
                    REFERENCES myObj (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When you attempt to execute this SQL, the following error is returned by SQL Server:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_myObj_ID' on table 'myObj' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

The error message indicates that SQL Server is declining to create the foreign key cascade relationship since deleting a single row could result in all the rows being deleted (or perhaps just multiple rows, not all, depending on data in the table!).

To illustrate this, consider the following data:

```
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO myObj (fk_ParentID) VALUES (7);
```

Which looks like:

[image: sample data]

If I could define the `ON DELETE CASCADE` action on this table, executing the following code would delete all rows in the table:

```
DELETE FROM myObj WHERE ID = 1;
```

Deleting the row with ID=1 would cascade through the row with fk_ParentID=1 which would cascade delete through fk_ParentID 2, etc, etc.  Most likely this is not the effect you want.

Comment: What if this is exactly the effect wanted?

Comment: Deleting previous comments. I'll leave the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77ae4/1) that works in Postgres, Oracle and MySQL, in case you want to use it.

Comment: Deleting all rows is irrelevant -- there's nothing stopping you from doing so with a simple one-to-many relationship between two tables. The problem is just as the error message states -- circular cascading relationships and multiple cascade paths to the same table are disallowed. This could be handled using a recursive CTE in a delete trigger.

Comment: Jon, would you care to expand on circular and cascading paths a bit more?  I'm really interested in the nuts and bolts of this issue!

Comment: Honestly I don't know exactly why those relationships are disallowed except, presumably, for self-protection and performance optimizations. They're both technically *possible*, just *disallowed*. Does that help at all?

Comment: I've been involved in programming since the mid 80s and know that you can do anything if you set your mind to it.  I can't for the life of me understand the technical limitation in the engine that would prevent this type of code from working, which is what leant me towards the estimate that the error message was in fact an attempt at protecting data from unexpected actions.  This makes me believe the developer who coded the error message was pulling at straws for a concise way to describe the issue when the came up with "multiple cascade paths".

Comment: I love that PostgreSQL can do it.

Comment: I'm sure there were internal design meetings when they made this decision. Having written a few table dependency traversal algorithms myself, I can say it's definitely helpful to eliminate those possibilities to reduce the complexity of the code needed to get the job done. While the argument for self-referential deletes does have some weight in my eyes, I *like* the disallowing of multiple cascade paths, because it almost always points to a table design issue.

Comment: Good point about the table design issue